# Hamburger Menu is not collapsing back on clicking on the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please check this website http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/buck/ on mobile and let me know why the hamburger menu is not collapsing back on clicking on the menu?

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you provide a [mcve] than a link to a webpage with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look and see this error in your *custom.js* file has two error line 5 and line 32. Check these errors.

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
at custom.js:5
at custom.js:32
```

For example in custom.js line 5; you got another `"use strict";` If you'll solve these error your problem will disappear and hamburger icon will turn x and turn back bars

**Update**

Problems:

1. Your theme upload bootstrap.js twice
2. Also you still have error in `custom.js` `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
   at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
   at custom.js:18
   at custom.js:22`
3. You place wrong tag at in index line 355

If you remove these js files from your footer.
 `custom.js` and `<script src="http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/buck/wp-content/themes/Buck%20Blue/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`your problems are solved.

Or try remove this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/buck/wp-content/plugins/faq-responsive/assets/js/accordion.js?ver=4.9.4"></script>`(faq-responsive plugin)

Comment: I have fixed it but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: First your icons are correct now :) Second the `navbar-collapse no-padding out collapse in` these class for showing menu, the ìn` when `out` menu will  disappear. I little time later I will update my response for answer.

Comment: I found it...It's FAQ Responsive plugin which is conflicting.